# Workaround for ActiveState Komodo bug with F10 keyboard shortcut?

Tags: komodo

I'd really like F10 to Step Over in my Komodo IDE, to match Visual Studio. Unfortunately F10 has been hardwired to select the File menu. This is a known bug (see http://bugs.activestate.com/show_bug.cgi?id=81657 ).

Has anyone found a workaround?

I'd rather not reconfigure Visual Studio and my crusty brain. I'm using Komodo version 5.2.4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's been a while since I've use Komodo so I make no guarantees that this will work, but the first thing I'd try is using an [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) script that looks for an F10 keypress in a Komodo window and sends instead whatever key sequence Komodo uses for the "Step Over" operation.